# bind9 slave error on transfer: dumping master file: /etc/bind/zones... open: permission denied

Tags: dns, bind

```
BIND 9.11.4-3 Ubuntu 18.10
```

The error is seen in the journal after the following which seems to indicate success, though there is an apparmor error which I don't understand

Lines are ordered with most recent at top :

```
 ....
Jan 15 16:00:21 vaio named[25553]: transfer of '0.0.10.in- 
addr.arpa/IN' from 10.0.0.110#53: Transfer status: success
....

 Jan 15 16:00:20 vaio audit[25553]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" 
 operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/named" 
  name="/etc/bind/zones/tmp-wTjV9cpi5S" pid=25553 comm="isc- 
  worker0000" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=126 ouid=126

 Jan 15 16:00:20 vaio named[25553]: dumping master file: 
 /etc/bind/zones/tmp-wTjV9cpi5S: open: permission denied
```

The zone files are in `/etc/bind/zones`, the permissions on that directory are :

```
drwxrwsr-x   2 bind bind  4096 2019-01-15 15:20 zones
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct location to store the slaves zone is /var/lib/bind, /etc/bind is the user configuration location. As you can see, apparmor denied the write in /etc/bind folder.

Update your slave zone to use any file in /var/lib/bind.

Answer (score 2):

The path you define to store slave zone is defined in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`, which is `directory "var/cache/bind"`.

Make sure bind group have the write access to that directory which you will store your db zones;

What I suggest to do is :

define `file slaves/$db_file_name` in `/etc/named.conf.local`.

And add a directory in `/var/cache/bind`

`sudo mkdir /var/cache/bind/slaves`

Then change ownership to bind group

`sudo chown bind:bind /var/cache/bind/slaves`

Answer (score 0):

I worked hard on this problem. (ubuntu 20.04 and bind9 DNS)

original source:https://linux.m2osw.com/bind-errors-between-masters-and-slaves

What I did is this:

```
vim /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named
```

original:

```
  /etc/bind/** r,
  /var/lib/bind/** rw,
  /var/lib/bind/ rw,
  /var/cache/bind/** lrw,
  /var/cache/bind/ rw,
```

add:

```
/var/named/** rw,
```

Wherever your zone files are, you need to add the path here.

and `reboot` =)